# How let telnet server mandates telnet client to run in passive mode?

Tags: c, telnet

I have written a basic Telnet Server in C language, and I am testing it against some telnet clients.

However, depending on the client I use (PuTTY, for example) then the client acts as Active by default.

Is there a way for the server to always mandate the client to act in passive mode?

I am asking this because, in my understanding, if the server mandates it, then I do not need to implement any protocol-specific details, only the basics to handle this mandatory passive mode. So, my Telnet Server will be at the end a simple TCP socket.

Update 1:

Here I describe the data received when a client connects to the server:

1. Launch the Telnet Server
2. Telnet Client Connects (and sends telnet protocol data)

```bash
received = {ffff1fffff20ffff18ffff27ffff01ffff03ffff03}
```

The data is hex encoded, and by decoding it according to the Telnet specification, the client is trying to establish some configuration before any data starts to be exchanged.

On the Telnet Server side, I simply ignore received data starting with 0xff (IAC code).

That solves the problem for a while.

3. Type some data on the Client side and hit enter
4. Telnet Server receives the data
5. Type some data on the Client side and hit enter
6. Telnet Server receives the data + telnet protocol data

Here is the received data (I sent "123456"):

```bash
received = {616263646566ffff18ffff27ffff01ffff03ffff03}
```

As you can see, I received what I sent, but I also got some telnet protocol stuff. That is because the Telnet Client is in Active mode.

I wish that at some intermediate step between 2 and 3, the Telnet Server could set the Telnet Client to run in Passive mode, so, I would not receive any Telnet Protocol data at step 6.

**Update 2:**

As requested in the comments for more details about the "Passive mode", I mean the Telnet negotiation mode: (1) Passive mode: where the Telnet Client/Server will not send any negotiation data, only user data; (2) Active mode: where the Telnet Client/Server will send the negotiation data to configure/handshake what are the features to be used/set.

And yes, I also could not find that to be specific to the protocol, only on PuTTY [documentation](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/config-ptelnet.html#:%7E:text=In%20a%20Telnet%20connection%2C%20there,as%20the%20connection%20is%20opened.)

Comment: The Telnet protocol is documented in great detail in [RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854).  Among other things, it discusses the specifics of negotiating protocol options.  HOWEVER, the word "passive"  does not appear anywhere in the spec, and it's unclear to me what you mean by "passive mode".

Comment: ftp has a passive mode — is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: Also, the question uses the word "mandate", but that's not something *any* server can actually do.  It may be able to *request* certain behavior from clients, and it can refuse service to those that do not comply with its expectations / demands, but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: I added "update 2" to tell about the active/passive behavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, I guess that is a better approach, where the Server refuses any negotiation from the Client, only Server to Client negotiation is allowed. I think I should go on this path for my implemetation.

Comment: Note that although you seem to be taking your idea of passive mode from PuTTY's bespoke connection-configuration option of that name, your description is not consistent with PuTTY's.  PuTTY's passive mode does not say that PuTTY will not engage in option negotiation *at all*, but rather that it will wait for the server to negotiate *first*.  It's not clear what PuTTY will do in this mode if the server starts sending regular data without negotiating any options, but my guess would be that PuTTY proceeds with option negotiation at that point or soon after.  You may be equipped to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The Telnet protocol and well-known options offer no support for what you describe.

> I mean the Telnet negotiation mode: (1) Passive mode: where the Telnet Client/Server will not send any negotiation data, only user data; (2) Active mode: where the Telnet Client/Server will send the negotiation data to configure/handshake what are the features to be used/set.

The Telnet specifications do not define a "passive mode" by any name.  There is no defined way for one side to request that the other refrain from attempting to negotiate protocol options, much less to refrain from sending any protocol commands at all.

> On the Telnet Server side, I simply ignore received data starting with 0xff (IAC code).

There are many more Telnet commands than those related to option negotiation.  Ignoring all Telnet commands makes your server not only impolite, but deficient.  You reference PuTTY's "passive mode", but even in that mode, PuTTY still emits Telnet commands for purposes other than option negotiation, and it likely still performs option negotiation too, albeit after allowing the server to negotiate first.

Additionally,

- Option negotiation and other protocol commands are asynchronous, which is why the approach you describe doesn't stall communication altogether, but that does not make it valid to ignore protocol commands.  The server should emit a response to each option negotiation command received, even if that response is negative.

  - And that will make it less likely for clients to make renewed attempts to negotiate the same options, but the server cannot say "never" to any option request, only "no".
- Although it is not obligated to accept requests or offers to *enable* non-default options, the server ***is*** obligated to honor requests to *disable* options:

  > Clearly, a party may always refuse
  > a request to enable, and must never refuse a request to disable some option

  ([RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854), p.2)
- The only way for a Telnet endpoint to receive a data byte with value 255 (decimal) is via the IAC mechanism.
- If a Telnet endpoint does not respond to AYT commands, then the other endpoint may sometimes conclude that the session has been dropped when in fact it is still active.
- A Telnet endpoint that ignores protocol commands does not support standard, expected terminal operations including break signals, interrupt process signals, erase character and erase line commands, and terminal synch.  If yours is a special-purpose Telnet implementation then perhaps some of these do not actually require any server-side action, but the synch, at least, is about the data stream between server and client, and I don't see any way that a conforming Telnet implementation can fail to provide for it.